# Viewing seed results in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, testing, seeding

I have created a seed file, ran `rake db:migrate` and `rake db:seed` everything seemed to have run fine.  However, I would now like to view the seeds in rails console, the name of the table is `usersinfo`.  How do I view to verify that the seeds populated correctly in console?

I have tried `usersinfo.all` in console but got the following error.

undefined method `all'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot directly view tables from rails console, however you can check if the table has data via the associated ActiveRecord model of that table

Ex:

if your table name is `usersinfo`
You should probably have a model called

```
class Userinfo < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name :usersinfo
end
```

and then in console you could do

```
Userinfo.all
```

NOTE: as per the rails convention, your table name should be plural, If you are not using the rails convention, you could always set the table name via `set_table_name:` method

and also, `.all` is a `ActiveRecord` class methods and works only with an `Activerecord Model`

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `.all` method for your model.

```
Userinfo.all
```

I would recommend you to read the [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-multiple-objects-in-batches)

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem. This did the trick for me:

```
rails runner 'p Userinfo.pluck :column_name`
```